# How to run the rails console in debug mode in Aptana Radrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, radrails, aptana

In Apatana Rad Rails, I want to run the rails console in debug mode. When I launch the debugger as shown below, debugger doesn't honor the break points.

```
debug script/console
```

I am able to run the rake tasks in debug mode by giving a similar command, i.e.

```
debug rake db:migrate
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're running RadRails 2. You might be able to get it to work correctly by right-clicking the script/console file and choosing Debug As > Ruby Application. The "Rails console" had some special hacks and contortions to handle commands like "debug rake ...", but under the hood it's doing the same as the Debug As action above and then tying the input/output to the console view.

Comment: I tried your suggestions on RadRails 3. I still encounter the same problem, i.e. the console is started in the debug mode, but the break points are not honored.